# Visualforce for Sublime Text - installation

Tags: mavensmate

I'm trying to install package for Visualforce bundle for Sublime Text, following exact order but unable to add the repository to MavensMate have anybody tried this before?

if you paste this url `https://github.com:brucardoso2/sublime-visualforce.git` it seems like does not exists but in the instructions

https://github.com/brucardoso2/sublime-visualforce

Manual

Manual

> Ctrl+Shift+p Type Add Repository Add this url:
>   https://github.com:brucardoso2/sublime-visualforce.git Open the
>   pallete again Ctrl+Shift+p Search for Visualforce and Install

Comment: Did you just try going to package control to begin with and looking for VisualForce? It should be there without having to add the url. Do you even have package control installed to begin with? If not, that could be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I able to found the reason why I was unable to install:

1. Go to your Sublime Text "Packages" directory (`Preferences` / `Browse Packages...`).
2. Then clone this GitHub repository:
    "cmd prompt > git clone https://github.com/brucardoso2/sublime-visualforce.git"
3. Open the pallete again Ctrl+Shift+p --> Search for Visualforce and Install